# Passing an image source to a scoped slot in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm lost, I've read the documentation on slots and looked over a few examples, but it's not clicking for me right now.

I cannot figure out how to pass an image source to `<img :src="">` within a slot.

**Relevant Blade.Php file:**

```
<image-upload>
    <template v-slot:completed-crop-preview >
        <div class="mb-2 flex space-x-2">
            <img :src="image" class="mb-2 w-16 h-16 rounded-full border-como border-2 border-dashed"
            alt="picture upload preview">
        </div>
    </template>
</image-upload>
```

**Relevant Vue.js template:**

```
<div>
    <slot name="completed-crop-preview" v-bind:image="imagePreview">
    </slot>
</div>
```

According to my developer tools, imagePreview is being set just fine and this did work just fine when before I moved the preview to a slot.

Comment: File *Blade.Php*, *Blade.php*, or *blade.php* (if the case of the filename matters)? Is there a standard name for it? What is the actual name of that file?

Comment: The blade file is `edit.blade.php` and the vue file is `image-upload.vue`. They seem to be working together just fine because everything works except for the `slot`

Comment: `imagePreview` is the an url or an object ?

Comment: `imagePreview` is a url - base64 to be exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could receive slot props as follows :

```
<image-upload>
    <template v-slot:completed-crop-preview="{image}" >
        <div class="mb-2 flex space-x-2">
            <img :src="image" class="mb-2 w-16 h-16 rounded-full border-como border-2 border-dashed"
            alt="picture upload preview">
        </div>
    </template>
</image-upload>
```